# Catching Exception and Transferin Exception In Netty

Tags: java, exception, netty

I am trying to recognize any exception after client receive or send message to server or from server. And If any exception happens, I want to close connection and say that "Connection has been closed because of 'this' exception" etc.

## CONNECTION

```
public static boolean connect(Host host, String message, int mode) throws Exception {
        EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        try {
            Bootstrap clientBootstrap = new Bootstrap();

            clientBootstrap.option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 100);

            clientBootstrap.group(group);
            clientBootstrap.channel(NioSocketChannel.class);
            clientBootstrap.remoteAddress(new InetSocketAddress(host.getIp(), host.getPort()));

            clientBootstrap.handler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                protected void initChannel(SocketChannel socketChannel) {

                    //TODO, TIMEOUT BILGISI ILE DOLDUR BURAYI
                    //socketChannel.pipeline().addLast(new ReadTimeoutHandler(1));
                    //socketChannel.pipeline().addLast("idleStateHandler", new IdleStateHandler(2, 2, 4));

                    socketChannel.pipeline().addLast(new FalconClientHandler(host, message, mode));
                }
            });

            ChannelFuture channelFuture = clientBootstrap.connect().sync();

            //TODO I NEED TO CATCH IT SOMEWHERE IN HERE
            channelFuture.channel().closeFuture().sync();
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Connection timed out --> " + e);
            host.setActive(false); //connection kurulamadı demektir. Bir sonraki mesaj geldiğinde bu hostun açılıp açılmadığı denenecek.
            return false;
        } finally {
            group.shutdownGracefully().sync();
            if (mode == 0) { //arka planda sunucu hep ayakta olmalı. Mode 0 da asla bağlantı kesilmemeli. Kesiliyorsa host kapanmıştır.
                host.setActive(false);
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

## CATCHING EXCEPTION

```
@Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause)throws Exception {
        cause.printStackTrace();
        //CLOSE CONNECTION AND I HAVE TO PASS THE INFORMATION WHY CONNECTION CLOSED
        ctx.close();
    }
```

## READ FUNCTION

```
@Override
    public void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext channelHandlerContext, ByteBuf in) {
        InetSocketAddress socketAddress = (InetSocketAddress) channelHandlerContext.channel().remoteAddress();
        InetAddress inetaddress = socketAddress.getAddress();
        String ipAddress = inetaddress.getHostAddress(); // IP address of client

        TCPHandshakeMessage tcpMessage;
        byte[] signal;
        String input = in.toString(CharsetUtil.US_ASCII);

        /*
         * mode 0 -> Amaç sunucuların ayakta olup olmadığını anlamak
         * mode 1 -> Amaç sunuculara mesaj göndermek
         * */
        if(this.mode == 1){  //MODE 1 BAŞLANGICI
            //I WRITE THIS ON PURPOSE
            double x = 12 / 0;
            System.err.println("MESSAGE SENT TO " + message + " IP : " + ipAddress);
            this.host.setActive(true);
            //TODO TCP MESSAGE SINIFINI KULLAN
            signal = message.getBytes();
            sendMessage(channelHandlerContext, signal);
            /*try {

            }catch (Exception e){
                System.out.println("An Error Occured " + e);
            }finally {
                channelHandlerContext.channel().close();
            }*/
        }
}
```

Should I use channelFuture.addListener() in CONNECTION area?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If it is HTTP 1.1 request you can handle the exception as follows:

```
@Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) {
        ctx.writeAndFlush(new DefaultFullHttpResponse(HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1, HttpResponseStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR))
                .addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
        LOG.error("Error occured", cause);
    }
```

`ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE` listener will close the connection after `writeAndFlush` succeeds